# Removing foreign accented characters before saving an Order in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have a problem wherein my Orders in Magento sometimes have shipping and billing address and name with foreign accents like àòèù. I want to convert them to English alphabets aoeu before saving the order in Magento.

I have the php code for it, which is a function

```
public function removeAccents($str)
{
    $a = array('À', 'Á', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Æ', 'Ç', 'È', 'É', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ð', 'Ñ', 'Ò', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Õ', 'Ö', 'Ø', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'Ü', 'Ý', 'ß', 'à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'å', 'æ', 'ç', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï', 'ñ', 'ò', 'ó', 'ô', 'õ', 'ö', 'ø', 'ù', 'ú', 'û', 'ü', 'ý', 'ÿ', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'Ð', 'd', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'H', 'h', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', '?', '?', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', '?', '?', 'L', 'l', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', '?', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'Œ', 'œ', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'Š', 'š', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'W', 'w', 'Y', 'y', 'Ÿ', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z', 'Ž', 'ž', '?', 'ƒ', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'A', 'a', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?');
    $b = array('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'AE', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'D', 'N', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'Y', 's', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'ae', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'n', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'y', 'y', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'D', 'd', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'H', 'h', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'IJ', 'ij', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'n', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'OE', 'oe', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'W', 'w', 'Y', 'y', 'Y', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z', 's', 'f', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'A', 'a', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'A', 'a', 'AE', 'ae', 'O', 'o');
    return str_replace($a, $b, $str);
}
```

and I use this function in the OnepageController saveShippingAction method like

```
$data['street'][0] = removeAccents($data['street'][0]);
$data['street'][1] = removeAccents($data['street'][1]);
$data['city'] = removeAccents($data['city']);
$data['city'] = "test";
$data['region'] = removeAccents($data['region']);
```

before the shipping address is saved.

I already have a OnepageController in my theme but it has a function that is not in the core Mage controller. Since I am modifying a core Mage controller here, just copying the function saveShippingAction somehow doesn't seem to work and the control goes to the core saveShippingAction function.

I also tried modifying my config.xml by adding the frontend attributes but it doesn't seem to work. I don't know if there is an easier way of achieving what I want, (like changing UTF-8 in etc/config.xml to Latin-1 ISO?).

I hope someone in this forum can throw some light on this issue and how to solve it! Thanks!!

Comment: Why not configure your database properly in the first place so it doesn't choke on accented characters?

Comment: so you want to change my actual address to something completely different, because you cant work with accented characters?

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense to preserve the addresses original characters, as the comment posters suggest. But if you **really** have to do it, it is better achieved by creating an observer to capture the `sales_quote_address_before_save` event.

In the observer function you can access the address model by calling

```
public function convertAddressChars(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) 
{ 
    $address = $observer->getEvent()->getObject();
    /**
    * Perform necessary manipulations, e.g.
    * $address->setData('city', removeAccents($address->getData('city'));
    */
}
```

But again, failing to preserve accents in the address data may lead to undeliverable orders.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a common problem - some shipping/delivery companies cannot cope with too many umlauts etc.

Another approach you may want to try is to tidy up the customer address details in the frontend javascript. I don't have the code to hand from when I tried this, however it is simple enough. You can do it in two ways - listen to the 'onblur' events and tidy up the text as the customer fills in their details, or you can do it as each section is submitted to make up the order.

Sorry that is just an approach rather than code, if you do take this route I may be able to dig something out for you...